# Video Codec for animating a graph plot - clean images with tiny delta between frames

Tags: video, codec

I'm looking for a video codec to encode video of a graph plot to which extra points are added over time.

The majority of the image does not change at all over the course of the video, and the area and the delta between frames will be confined to a very small area as points are added to the plot.

A codec that simply stored the deltas between frames would probably store the whole video very efficiently even without compression.

There is no audio, the video will be created on windows and only windows playback is required.

What codecs would be suitable for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [WMV9 screen codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video#Windows_Media_Video_Screen) would be a windows only option - it's optimized for screen recordings, which is exactly the scenario you're describing.
- You could use WebM/VP9 in lossless mode (though that *may* need an additional codec installed).
- APNG/MPNG is an option if they're short videos.